# Insert layout with different values

Tags: android, for-loop, android-activity, layout

I want to insert a few LinearLayouts, but it doesn't work like it should. It inserts just one, but it should insert more.

```
LinearLayout commentsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_comment_container);
                    commentsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    commentsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    for (int i = 0; i < postView.commentLenght(); i++) {
                        Log.e("LENGTH", postView.commentLenght()+"x"+i);
                        LinearLayout commentContainer = new LinearLayout(PostViewActivity.this);
                        commentContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        LinearLayout userContainer = new LinearLayout(PostViewActivity.this);
                        userContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        userContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                        commentContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                        commentContainer.setPadding(25,0,0,0);
                        ImageView commentImage = new ImageView(PostViewActivity.this);
                        commentImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) ((float) width / 6), (int) ((float) width / 6)));
                        commentImage.setImageBitmap(postView.getComment(i).getImage());
                        TextView commentText = new TextView(PostViewActivity.this);
                        commentText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        commentText.setText(postView.getComment(i).getText());
                        TextView displayUserText = new TextView(PostViewActivity.this);
                        displayUserText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        displayUserText.setText(postView.getComment(i).getDisplayName());
                        Log.d("TEXT", postView.getComment(i).getText());
                        Log.e("TEXT", displayUserText.getText()+"");
                        displayUserText.setTag(postView.getComment(i).getUsername());
                        displayUserText.setTextSize(12);
                        displayUserText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                        userContainer.addView(commentImage);
                        userContainer.addView(displayUserText);
                        commentContainer.addView(userContainer);
                        commentContainer.addView(commentText);
                        commentsContainer.addView(commentContainer);

                    }
```

Another strange thing: the first Log.d is always the correct one, but the second one is always the same. What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be greatly cleaned up by using XML resource files. As each of the comments takes the same form, the same layout can be used for each. You can fill different values into the layout as you desire. These can all be added to a ViewGroup within another layout.

Programmatically generating layouts is much more error prone and complex than using an XML layout.

Doing some reading into the Android official documentation is absolutely worth it! https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's really better :-)